# Minimum spanning tree for a weighted square grid

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I have a particular grid with weighted edges connecting each vertex:

[image: grid]

From this I'm looking for an easy method to obtain a Minimum Spanning Tree.

I can easily check columns or rows and remove all but the lowest weight, but this will only provide me with a regular spanning tree instead of the desired MST. Columns, for example:

[image: columns]

I do know I can use the various classic algorithms such as Kruskal's, Prim's, or Boruvka's, but I'm wondering if there's an easier method for grids specifically since it was easy enough to get a regular tree (and if the easiest method happens to be one of the classic algorithms, which might be the best suited for grids).

Comment: You have just this particular grid, or is this an example of a more general construction? If the latter, what is the pattern for the edge weights?

Comment: It's a general construction. The edge weights are just assigned randomly.